# git: fatal: could not find pack 'pack-xxxxxxx.pack'

Tags: git

Having a strange problem. Not sure how I caused it.

```
$ git gc
Enumerating objects: 625644, done.
Counting objects: 100% (625644/625644), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (126399/126399), done.
Writing objects: 100% (625644/625644), done.
Total 625644 (delta 497529), reused 622563 (delta 494488), pack-reused 0
fatal: could not find pack 'pack-6f30656f301f5f88438a5216f1df773bafcdf6d3.pack'
fatal: failed to run repack
```

I can see the file it's referring to, not sure if it's corrupted or not. It's all binary.

```
$ ls -lsah .git/objects/pack/pack-6f30656f301f5f88438a5216f1df773bafcdf6d3.pack
1168 -rw-------  1 javier  staff   584K Oct  8  2021 .git/objects/pack/pack-6f30656f301f5f88438a5216f1df773bafcdf6d3.pack
```

Looking a little closer, this hash doesn't have an accompanying `.rev`/`.idx` like the rest of the `.pack` files have in this directory. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be addressed with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), which now avoids breakage of "[`git pack-objects --cruft`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e224f26892ffc3e2cb98fd68c6f74dc3d650ffc8/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt#L99)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects#Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt---cruft))</sup> due to inconsistency between the way the code enumerates packfiles in the repository.

See [commit 73320e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22) (07 Jun 2023) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e224f26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e224f26892ffc3e2cb98fd68c6f74dc3d650ffc8), 26 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/repack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22): only collect fully-formed packs
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Michael Haggerty</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> To partition the set of packs based on which ones are "kept" (either they have a `.keep` file, or were otherwise marked via the `--keep-pack` option) and "non-kept" ones (anything else), [`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22/Documentation/git-repack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> uses its `collect_pack_filenames()` function.
>
> Ordinarily, we would rely on a convenience function such as `get_all_packs()` to enumerate and partition the set of packs.
> But `collect_pack_filenames()` uses `readdir()` directly to read the contents of the `"$GIT_DIR/objects/pack"` directory, and adds each entry ending in ".pack" to the appropriate list (either kept, or non-kept as above).
>
> This is subtly racy, since `collect_pack_filenames()` may see a pack that is not fully staged (i.e., it is missing its "`.idx`" file).
> Ordinarily, this doesn't cause a problem.
> But it can cause issues when generating a cruft pack.
>
> This is because `git repack` feeds (among other things) the list of existing kept packs down to [`git pack-objects --cruft`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt#L99)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects#Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt---cruft))</sup> to indicate that any kept packs will not be removed from the repository (so that the cruft pack machinery can avoid packing objects that appear in those packs as cruft).
>
> But `read_cruft_objects()` lists packfiles by calling `get_all_packs()`.
> So if a "`.pack`" file exists (necessary to get that pack to appear to `collect_pack_filenames()`), but doesn't have a corresponding "`.idx`" file (necessary to get that pack to appear via `get_all_packs()`), we'll complain with:
>
> ```
> fatal: could not find pack '.tmp-5841-pack-a6b0150558609c323c496ced21de6f4b66589260.pack'
> ```
>
> Fix the above by teaching `collect_pack_filenames()` to only collect packs with their corresponding `*.idx` files in place, indicating that those packs have been fully staged.
>
> There are a couple of things worth noting:
>
> - Since each entry in the `extra_keep` list (which contains the
>   `--keep-pack` names) has a `*.pack` suffix, we'll have to swap the
>   suffix from "`.pack`" to "`.idx`", and compare that instead.
> - Since we use the the `fname_kept_list` to figure out which packs to delete (with [`git repack -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L60)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt--d))</sup>), we would have previously deleted a
>   `*.pack` with no index (since the existince of a "`.pack`" file is
>   necessary and sufficient to include that pack in the list of
>   existing non-kept packs).
>
>   Now we will leave it alone (since that pack won't appear in the
>   list). This is far more correct behavior, since we don't want
>   to race with a pack being staged. Deleting a partially staged pack
>   is unlikely, however, since the window of time between staging a
>   pack and moving its `.idx` file into place is miniscule.
>
>   Note that this window does *not* include the time it takes to
>   receive and index the pack, since the incoming data goes into
>   "`$GIT_DIR/objects/tmp_pack_XXXXXX`", which does not end in "`.pack`"
>   and is thus ignored by `collect_pack_filenames()`.
>
> In the future, this function should probably be rewritten as a callback to `for_each_file_in_pack_dir()`, but this is the simplest change we could do in the short-term.

---

And, still with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), we create `.pack` and then `.idx`, we consider only packfiles that have `.idx` usable (those with only `.pack` are not ready yet), so we should remove `.idx` before removing `.pack` for consistency.

See [commit 0dd1324](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dd1324a73e404a2b02356c77088ec1f71beec11) (20 Jun 2023) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b2166b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2166b0d496c2f3df96929da300039a01227e719), 29 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`packfile`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dd1324a73e404a2b02356c77088ec1f71beec11): delete `.idx` files before `.pack` files
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When installing a packfile, we place the `.pack` file before the `.idx` file.
> The intention is that Git scans for `.idx` files in the pack directory and then loads the `.pack` files from that list.
>
> However, when we delete packfiles, we do not do this in the reverse order as we should.
> The `unlink_pack_path()` method deletes the `.pack` followed by the `.idx`.
>
> This creates a window where the process could be interrupted between the `.pack` deletion and the `.idx` deletion, leaving the repository in a state that looks strange, but isn't actually too problematic if we assume the pack was safe to delete.
> The `.idx` without a `.pack` will cause some overhead, but will not interrupt other Git processes.
>
> This ordering was introduced into the '[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0dd1324a73e404a2b02356c77088ec1f71beec11/Documentation/git-repack.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> builtin by [a1bbc6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1bbc6c0176f1fa2d4aa571cc0183a1f0ff9b285) ("`repack`: rewrite the shell script in C", 2013-09-15, Git v1.8.5-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dec034a34e3887beaea9a7a390fd950346806c1e)), though we must be careful to track history through the code move in [8434e85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8434e85d5f9602a82f6b34ba82a9cb9e559a2d3b) ("`repack`: refactor pack deletion for future use", 2019-06-10, Git v2.23.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4308d81d456c8c3ecc2c33af7f4d834de95130b9) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c9b961d7eb15fb583a2a812088713a68a85f1c0)) to see that.
>
> This became more important after [73320e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22) ("[`builtin/repack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22/builtin/repack.c): only collect fully-formed packs", 2023-06-07, Git v2.42.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e224f26892ffc3e2cb98fd68c6f74dc3d650ffc8) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9e066fa63149291a55f383cfa113d8bdbdaa6b3)) changed how '`git repack`' scanned for packfiles for use in the cruft pack process.
> It previously looked for `.pack` files, but that was problematic due to the order that packs are installed: repacks between the creation of a `.pack` and the creation of its `.idx` would result in hard failures.
>
> There is an independent proposal about what to do in the case of a `.idx` without a `.pack` during this '`git repack`' scenario, but this change is focused on deleting `.pack` files more safely.
>
> Modify the order to delete the `.idx` before the `.pack`.
> The rest of the modifiers on the `.pack` should still come after the `.pack` so we know all of the presumed properties of the packfile as long as it exists in the filesystem, in case we wish to reinstate it by re-indexing the `.pack` file.

---

The recent change to "[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6a5e1a22e0fcafbcc67a2b098cc13150f8aaf4a/Documentation/git-repack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> made it react less nicely when a leftover `.idx` file that no longer has the corresponding `.pack` file in the repository: that has been corrected with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023).

See [commit def390d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/def390d5939d97f4bd642684e0554885e716370e) (11 Jul 2023) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
See [commit 0af0672](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0af067276ee204147e6da933d19ec5ab791aa26d) (11 Jul 2023) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c6a5e1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6a5e1a22e0fcafbcc67a2b098cc13150f8aaf4a), 18 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/repack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/def390d5939d97f4bd642684e0554885e716370e): avoid dir traversal in `collect_pack_filenames()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When repacking, the function `collect_pack_filenames()` is responsible for collecting the set of existing packs in the repository, and partitioning them into "`kept`" (if the pack has a "`.keep`" file or was given via `--keep-pack`) and "`nonkept`" (otherwise) lists.
>
> This function comes from the original C port of git-repack.sh from back in [a1bbc6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1bbc6c0176f1fa2d4aa571cc0183a1f0ff9b285) ("`repack`: rewrite the shell script in C", 2013-09-15, Git v1.8.5-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dec034a34e3887beaea9a7a390fd950346806c1e)), where it first appears as `get_non_kept_pack_filenames()`.
> At the time, the implementation was a fairly direct translation from the relevant portion of `git-repack.sh`, which looped over the results of
>
> ```
> find "$PACKDIR" -type f -name '*.pack'
> ```
>
> either ignoring the pack as kept, or adding it to the list of existing packs.
>
> So the choice to directly translate this function in terms of `readdir()` in [a1bbc6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a1bbc6c0176f1fa2d4aa571cc0183a1f0ff9b285) made sense.
> At the time, it was possible to refine the C version in terms of `packed_git` structs, but was never done.
>
> However, manually enumerating a repository's packs via `readdir()` is confusing and error-prone.
> It leads to frustrating inconsistencies between which packs Git considers to be part of a repository (i.e., could be found in the list of packs from `get_all_packs()`), and which packs `collect_pack_filenames()` considers to meet the same criteria.
>
> This bit us in [73320e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22) ("[`builtin/repack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/73320e49add4b56aba9bf5236a216498fa8ccc22/builtin/repack.c): only collect fully-formed packs", 2023-06-07, Git v2.42.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e224f26892ffc3e2cb98fd68c6f74dc3d650ffc8) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9e066fa63149291a55f383cfa113d8bdbdaa6b3)), and again in the previous commit.
>
> Prevent these issues from biting us in the future by implementing the `collect_pack_filenames()` function by looping over an array of pointers to `packed_git` structs, ensuring that we use the same criteria to determine the set of available packs.
>
> One gotcha here is that we have to ignore non-local packs, since the original version of `collect_pack_filenames()` only looks at the local pack directory to collect existing packs.

Comment: Is there any workaround to use until 2.42 is released?

Comment: @JiriTousek I have not seen any so far.

Comment: @JiriTousek The workaroung that worked for me was to delete the local repo and clone it again.

Comment: @Arjun That should work indeed. That being said, Git 2.42 should be out before the end of this month. (August, 21st)

Comment: Git 2.42 is now out and I can confirm it fixed the issue for me.